# Update jinja2 variables in combination with JQuery & Flask framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

I encountered a problem while improving my webapp that I have built with flask.

Because a POST makes a page refresh (which takes long) I wanted to change it to a JQuery POST.

Everything ok because JQuery POST's in the background, but how can I make Jinja to reread the db without refreshing?

1) I know jinja2 is server-side and this can be a problem. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: you really can't render the whole page using jinja2 without refreshing. A part of the page can be refreshed by rendering a desired html element using a jinja2 template for that element, returning it as the ajax response and having jquery put it instead/in addition to the html element you need refreshed. Please post the proper code to focus your question.

Comment: Why would you want to rerender the whole page?